# String + variable how?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

Im a beginner learning Qt/C++
and I got into an error:
I wanted to know how can I put a variable in this case "username" next to a string in the lines below.

```
QString username = ui->lineEdit->text();

QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText("Your username is: " VARIABLEHERE);
msgBox.exec();
```

So how to line it or should I use other function ? than msgBox.setText()

Answer (score 10):

The nice Qt way is:

```
msgBox.setText(QString("Your username is: %1").arg(VARIABLEHERE));
```

For more information see [QString::arg](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#arg)

Comment: This one Worked, Thank you all guys :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want translation support:

```
msgBox.setText(tr("Your username is: %1").arg(VARIABLEHERE));
```

If you concatenate then all languages will have to use the same sentence semantics, and well... they can't.

Answer (score 3):

```
msgBox.setText("Your username is: "+VARIABLEHERE);
```

Comment: Depends on the type of `VARIABLEHERE`. If it is a `const char*` then this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

i think + should help:
`msgBox.setText("Your username is: " + username );`

Answer (score 0):

Related:
When you debug using "std::cout" it works like this with QStrings:

```
cout << any_qstring.toUtf8().constData() << number_variable << endl;
```

Otherwise the compiler will tell you that "<<" is ambiguous.

Edit: it's even easier to call `toStdString`

```
cout << myString.toStdString() << some_int << endl;
```

And if you want to parse numbers from strings, use `QString::number(your_double);`